# Is there anything else I can do to troubleshoot my 980ti?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, displayport

I bought an Asus Strix 980ti about 5 months ago.  I've been having problems with one of my monitors going in and out quickly.  Like, every 3 seconds it shuts off, then back on.  I thought my monitor was going bad, but when I moved the ports around on the video card, I noticed any monitor I have plugged into my first display port does the same thing. I really don't want to RMA this thing, and have them send it back, and them not find a problem.  The reason I think this may happen, is that this problem only happens about once a week, for five minutes.  So, once a week, for five minutes, my monitor turns on and off every 3 seconds.....it's frustrating, but not the worst thing ever.

Here's the steps I took to narrow it down to the video card.

1. I tried a different monitor on the same port, with the same problem.
2. I tried a new cable, with multiple monitors, with the same problem.
3. I plugged four monitors into all of the display ports for a week, and the one connected to the dp 1, was the only one that had a problem.

So, are there any kind of error logs for nvidia that I could see something that's going on?

Honestly, I'd rather just get my money back, since at the time I spent about $620 on it, and now I could get a 1080 for about that much.  I have never RMA'd anything, and am worried that they will get the card, and find nothing wrong with it, and I'll be charged for that, and get a broken card back.

I know I could just use the other ports, and be fine, but I paid a lot for that card, and I really don't want to keep it if a display port goes out every 4 months.

Any advice is appreciated.